# uniform norm: using $\sup(A+B)=\sup A+\sup B$ to proof $|||f(x)|+|g(y)|||=||f(x)||+||g(y)||$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and $g:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be bounded functions.
The uniform norm ist defined by $||f(x)||=\sup\{|f(x)|| x\in D\}$.

Now my question:

I know this theorem: If $A,B$ are non-empty, upper bounded sets and $A+B=\{a+b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$ then it follows that $\sup(A+B)=\sup A+\sup B$.

Define $A=\{|f(x)|| x\in D\}, B = \{|g(y)|| y\in D\}$ and $A+B=\{|f(x)|+|g(y)| | x,y\in D\}$

Can I conclude from that $|||f(x)|+|g(y)|||=\sup(A+B)=\sup A+\sup B=||f(x)||+||g(y)||$ for every $x,y\in D$?

Answer (score 2):

So there are a few confusions here let me try to eleborate on all of them.

The first one is that you should not be notating this by $||f(x)||$, that implies you are looking at a specific value. You want to say something like $||f||$, which implies you are looking at the whole function.

Now as you have observed, if we let $f(D)$ be the image of $f$, the norm of $f$ is the supremum of the set $f(D)$. Ditto for $g$ and the set $g(D)$. But here is the important thing:
$$(f+g)(D) \neq f(D)+g(D)$$

Let me give an example of such maps. Let $f=g: \mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be the identity maps. then $(f+g)(n) = n+n = 2n$, so the image is precisely the set of even integers $2\mathbb{Z}$. However the image of both $f$ and $g$ are the entirity of $\mathbb{Z}$ so that when you do a set sum, it also ends up being the whole thing.

In general, you can only say $$(f+g)(D) \subseteq f(D)+g(D)$$ as the former contains elements of the form $f(x)+g(x)$ for $x\in D$, while the latter contains elements like $f(x)+g(y)$ for $x,y\in D$. So taking sup you would say $$||f+g|| \leq ||f||+||g||$$ which is the triangle inequality.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand it completely:$A$ and $B$ as I defined them are both non-empty, upper bounded sets and $A+B=\{|f(x)|+|g(y)| | x,y\in D\}=\{a+b | a\in A , b\in B\}$. I understand your example but I still can't see that I don't meet the requirement for the theorem  $\sup(A+B)=\sup A+\sup B$. I want to emphasise $||f+g|| \neq |||f|+|g|||=\sup(A+B)=\sup A+\sup B=||f||+||g||$ , so I don't claim $||f+g|| =||f||+||g||$

Comment: $\sup(A+B)$ is not the norm you are looking for, as i mentioned. Try rereading the last part to see why. (also replacing $f$ with $|f|$ in my example gives the same thing.)

Comment: I think, I know now what you mean.: $\sup (A+B)=\sup\{|f(x)|+|g(y)|\;\: | x,y\in D\}\neq ||\: |f|+|g|\:|| =\sup\{ \vert \:|f(x)|+|g(x)| \: \vert \:\;| x\in D\}$

Comment: It does not matter in your example whether $|f|+|g|$ or $f+g$ because you could also define the functions $h_1:= |f|$ and $h_2:=|g|$, so that you reach a form like: $||\: |f|+|g|\:||= ||\: h_1+h_2\:|| =\sup\{ \vert \:h_1(x) + h_2(x) \: \vert \:\;| x\in D\}$? The point ist, that 
$||\: |f|+|g|\:||\leq \sup\{ \vert \:|f(x)|+|g(y)| \: \vert \:\;| x,y\in D\}$ because only $\{ \vert \:|f(x)|+|g(x)| \: \vert \:\;| x\in D\} \subseteq \{ \vert \:|f(x)|+|g(y)| \: \vert \:\;| x,y\in D\}$ can be assumed.

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion does not hold in this case, because
$$
\| |f(x)| + |g(y)| \| = 
\sup\{|f(x)| + |g(x)| : x\in D\}$$
Is not equivalent to $ \sup\{|f(x)| + |g(y)| : x,y\in D\} $ in general. Here's a counterexample: Let $D = [-1,1]$, and define the indicator function $\chi_E(x)$ to be $1$ for $x\in E$ and $0$ for $x\notin E$. Notice that $|\chi_E(x)| = \chi_E(x)$ for all $x\in D$. Then we have
\begin{equation}
||\chi_{[-1,0)}(x)|| = 1, \\
||\chi_{[0,1)}(x)|| = 1, \\
||\chi_{[-1,0)}(x) + \chi_{[0,1)}(x)|| = ||\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)|| = 1.
\end{equation}
So here we see that $||\chi_{[-1,0)}(x) + \chi_{[0,1)}(x)|| = 1$ but
$||\chi_{[-1,0)}(x)|| + ||\chi_{[0,1)}(x)|| = 2$.